# OpenGL sharetexture to copy is null

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, textures

I had a Win32 handle shared from Vulkan and created a shared texture in OpenGL ,like:

```
#ifdef WIN32
        texGl.handle = device.getMemoryWin32HandleKHR({ info.memory, vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eOpaqueWin32 });
#else
        texGl.handle = device.getMemoryFdKHR({ info.memory, vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eOpaqueFd });
#endif
        GLASSERT(texGl.handle);
        auto req = device.getImageMemoryRequirements(texGl.texVk.image);
        // Create a 'memory object' in OpenGL, and associate it with the memory allocated in Vulkan
        glCreateMemoryObjectsEXT(1, &texGl.memoryObject);
#ifdef WIN32
        glImportMemoryWin32HandleEXT(texGl.memoryObject, req.size, GL_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_WIN32_EXT, texGl.handle);
#else
        glImportMemoryFdEXT(texGl.memoryObject, req.size, GL_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_FD_EXT, texGl.handle);
        // fd got consumed
        //texGl.fd = -1;
#endif
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texGl.oglId);
        GLCALL(glTextureStorageMem2DEXT(texGl.oglId, texGl.mipLevels, format, texGl.imgSize.width, texGl.imgSize.height, texGl.memoryObject, info.offset));
```

then

I use copy,like:

```
glCopyImageSubData(hsrcTex, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, hDesTex,
            GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 1);
```

then I getImageData,like:

```
        GLsizei size = width * height * pixsize;
        GLubyte* data = (GLubyte*)malloc(size);
        //(GLuint texture, GLint level, GLenum format, GLenum type, GLsizei bufSize, void *pixels)
        glGetTextureImage(GLuint(desTexture->getID()), 0, (GLenum)desTexture->getFormat(), desTexture->getType(), size, data);
        glGetTextureImage(GLuint(desTexture->getID()), 1, (GLenum)desTexture->getFormat(), desTexture->getType(), size, data);
```

but the mipMap is any Nums,data is NULL.

I'm sure the srcTexture is have data to save the ".png".
How can I perform copy???

Answer (score -1):

This is a mistake on my part: the code in question above is fine.

Gl reported an error during use.
Because there is no error detection with GL.

The void glTextureStorageMem2DEXT (GLuint texture, GLsizei levels, GLenum internalFormat, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLuint memory, GLuint64 offset).

https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_vk_simple_interop

I mistakenly used Format instead of internalFormat as required. When I fixed this small error, the program worked fine.

:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).